# Linebreaking in table goes across columns

Tags: longtable, columns

First time poster so please be kind.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=10pt,font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf,labelsep=endash]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[bottom,flushmargin,hang,multiple]{footmisc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[sort]{natbib}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{appendix}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=false}
\hypersetup{citebordercolor=1 1 1} \hypersetup{linkbordercolor=1 1 1}
\usepackage{array}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.8}
\newcommand\VRule{\color{lightgray}\vrule width 0.5pt}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[small,compact]{titlesec}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{a}{}{;}
\newcommand{\gray}{\rowcolor[gray]{.9}}
\newcommand{\todo}[1] {\textbf{\textcolor{red}{#1}}}
\usepackage[margin=.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titling}
\begin{document}
\section*{Research interests}
\begin{longtable}{p{1in}!{\VRule}p{5.5in}}
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textit{Research interests continued}}\vspace{.1in}\\
\endhead
\multicolumn{2}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}}\\
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
International Political Economy             & Effectiveness of foreign aid \\
            & Differential effects of economic and military aid\\
            & Foreign aid during civil conflict\vspace{.1in}\\
Conflict            & \\
            & \vspace{.1in}\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

This creates the following:

[image: Screenshot]

The lines in the second column should not have the skip. Also, if anyone has a method of keeping LaTeX from hyphenating within the table, that would be great too.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx. To upload an image you can use the image button as usual but remove `!` from the generated markup. This makes a link, and a user with edit rights will put the `!` back and inline the image later. Thanks for posting a complete document, that always helps although I suspect you could have trimmed the package loading a bit and made it more minimal while still showing the problem:-)

Comment: You can use `>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{1in}` to set the contents ragged (and not hyphenated)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ah, thanks for the image explanation. And, yes, I probably should have trimmed the preamble, but you know how that goes... So if there are any suggestions on unnecessary/outdated/alternative packages, I am grateful to entertain those as well.

Comment: The image looks as I would expect, which space do you not want?

Comment: The main reason fror trimming the preamble is not that you may be using oudated package it's that some questions require `\tracingall` and other debugging tools and loading a few thousand lines of unused code makes debugging harder:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The line "Differential..." should be horizontally aligned with the line "Political econ-" Ah, and understood about the preamble.

Comment: If you mean the space between Effectiveness and Differetial that is implied by using a tabular layout which puts each entry into a rectangular cell. The first row of the table is tall because of the large entry in the first cell then differential effects.. is on the second row.

Comment: Ah, of course. Ok, so back to the drawing board.

Comment: @JWells -- your explicit description of what you want (in the comment to david carlisle) is "disappearing" among the comments.  if you edited it directly into the question, it would get better attention.

Comment: Thanks @barbarabeeton, but the cause of the issue has been made pretty clear.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
\begin{longtable}{>{\hspace{0pt}}p{1in}!{\VRule}>{\hspace{0pt}}p{5.5in}}
```

TeX doesn't hyphenate the first word in a paragraph. And use package `ragged2e` and then

```
\begin{longtable}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{1in}!{\VRule}>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{5.5in}}
```

`\RaggedRight` aloows hyphenation, `\raggedright` not

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
%\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array,longtable}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{>{\RaggedRight}p{1in} | >{\RaggedRight}p{5.5in}}
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textit{Research interests continued}}\\
\endhead
\multicolumn{2}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}}\\
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
International Political Economy             & Effectiveness of foreign aid \\
            & Differential effects of economic and military aid\\
            & Foreign aid during civil conflict\\
Conflict            & \\
            & 
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]